# Roslyn ImportAdderService doesn't visit trivia

Tags: c#, roslyn

The `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.ImportAdderService.AddImportsAsync` method only visits non-trivia syntax nodes, and therefore doesn't add namespace imports for them. This leads to the results, that cref's in xml documentation comments cannot be simplified to their short names, when using the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Simplification.Simplifier`.

The biggest problem that I have with this, is that the simplification can lead to inconsistent results. Assume that you have multiple cref's, and for one cref, you have a namespace import (introduced due to another type, that is actually used in a non-trivia node). Then, this one cref's gets shortened, and the others don't.

For clarification.

**Before applying `ImportAdderService` and `Simplifier`:**

```
namespace Namespace
{
  /// <summary>
  /// <see cref=""System.Collections.IEnumerable"" />
  /// <see cref=""System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable{T}"" />.
  /// </summary>
  internal class MyDeclaration
  {
    System.Collections.IEnumerable Field;
  }
}
```

**After applying `ImportAdderService` and `Simplifier`:**

```
using System.Collections;

namespace Namespace
{
  /// <summary>
  /// <see cref=""IEnumerable"" />
  /// <see cref=""System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable{T}"" />.
  /// </summary>
  internal class MyDeclaration
  {
    IEnumerable Field;
  }
}
```

**Question**

Can I work around this issue? We definitely want to add usings for all types referenced in cref tags.

Or is this even by design?

I guess it is indeed a missing feature, to tell the `ImportAdderService` to visit trivia syntax nodes.

Comment: Now is a good time to ask for changes in the product. It has not been shipped yet. The team responds well to GitHub issues.

Comment: I concur with @usr, you should head over to the https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn repo and file an issue; someone will either answer your question / note it as an actual issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually, it's very interesting, but sometimes it also receives good attention, if you post a SO question in the gitter channel... whereas some issues on github are never answered by anyone.